# Deleting all Docs in a Collection Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform

Let's say i am trying to delete all docs in a collection called `attributes` in Firebase Cloud Firestore with Typescript.

I tried:

```
const collectionRef = collection(db, 'projectAttributes');

try {
  const snapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef)

  // Delete each document in the collection
  const deletePromises = snapshot.docs.map((doc :any) => doc.ref.delete())
  await Promise.all(deletePromises)

  return (`Deleted ${deletePromises.length} documents from the 'projectAttributes' collection.`)

} catch (error) {
  return(`Error deleting documents: ${error}`);
}
```

But i get the error that `delete()` does not exist.

I also tried the approach given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62090827/how-to-delete-all-the-documents-in-a-firestore-collection-database) StackOverflow Question.

```
db.collection('cities').get().then(querySnapshot => {
     querySnapshot.docs.forEach(snapshot => {
        snapshot.ref.delete();
    })
})
```

However i first had to change `db.collection('cities')` to `collection(db, 'cities')` which then delivers the following error `Property 'get' does not exist on type 'CollectionReference<DocumentData>'`
Trying to fix this it all goes downhill even more.

**Note**

`firebase -v` delivers `11.24.1`

`npm -v` delivers `8.11.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You anyways cannot delete snapshots that way. Also it might be related to using map in TS. I have tried and tested the code below. Instead try this:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import {
  getFirestore,
  collection,
  getDocs,
  deleteDoc,
} from 'firebase/firestore';

const collectionRef = collection(db, 'projectAttributes');
const docsArr = [];
try {
  const snapshot = await getDocs(collectionRef);
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {
    docsArr.push(deleteDoc(doc.ref));
  });
  Promise.all(docsArr).then(() => console.log('documents deleted'));
} catch (error) {
   return `Error deleting documents: ${error}`;
}
```